# RPA.Windows tests need Physical/Remote desktop screen to run

Tags: windows, robotframework, ui-automation, rpa

I am new to Windows app automation. I am using RPA.Windows library to automate our windows application. RPA.Windows tests need Physical/Remote desktop screen in unlocked state to run.
Is there a way to run without Physical/Remote desktop screen? Because I need to run tests as soon as nightly build is generated. Physical desktop/remote desktop screen is getting locked after 10 mins due to inactivity.

Appreciate any help

Regards
Revathi

I tried to configure Physical desktop screen active always which is not possible.

Comment: Nothing to do with RPA.Windows - its effectively a security measure from Microsoft.

Comment: @rasjani Is there a way to have Physical desktop screen unlocked always?

Comment: Configure your windows to auto login to user account and disable sleep and screen saver/screen lock.  Also, worth pointing out that is you use something if you have something like jenkins in the mix, how you start the jenkins varies from what is normally suggested by jenkins docs..

Comment: @rasjani Thanks for your response. Is there a way to run tests without Physical/Remote desktop screen?